# Asynchronous function not returning callback for MongoDB connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, express

I have a MongoDB connect call that crashes a heroku app..

I have been editing what was originally localHost code (was working perfectly) to work with Heroku MongoDb addons (like MongoLab), but how do I get `someDBcollectionVariable` to work with `someDBcollectionVariable.find()`

```
//MongoDB
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var db;
var MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
var PORT = process.env.PORT;
var testColl;

function dbConnect() {

  return mongodb.MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, function(err, database) {
    if(err) throw err;

    db = database;
    var testColl = db.collection('test');

    app.listen(PORT);
    console.log('Listening on port ' + PORT);

    return testColl;

  });
}

//calls then look like
app.post('/add', function (req, res) {    

    testColl.insert(
        {
            "title" : req.body.title,
            "quantity" : parseInt(req.body.quantity)

        },
            function (err, doc) {

                getAll(res);

            });
});

//and getAll looks like this
function getAll(res) {

    testColl.find().sort( { value: 1 } ).toArray(function (err, docs) {

        res.json({docs: docs});
    });
}
```

Before moving that code inside `dbConnect()`, `testColl.find..` was generating a ResponseError because the connect code was completing before the variable could be set?

Answer (score 0):

Returning a value from an asynchronous function makes no sense. To use the a value, you need to pass it to a callback function. The same goes for errors (you can't throw asynchronously). A fixed version of your code could look like:

```
//MongoDB
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var db;
var MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
var PORT = process.env.PORT;
var testColl;

function dbConnect(callback) {
    mongodb.MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, function (err, database) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        db = database;

        database.collection('test', function (err, testColl) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }

            app.listen(PORT);
            console.log('Listening on port ' + PORT);

            callback(null, testColl); 
        });
    });
}

//calls then look like
dbConnect(function (err, testColl) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.stack || err.message);
    }

    testColl.find...
});
```

Comment: Would ajax calls then look like this `app.post('/add', function (testColl, req, res) {..testColl.insert..` or like this `dbConnect.app.post(..`

Comment: Or would it be `dbConnect(testColl).app.post(..`

Comment: It's difficult to tell. I don't know what app is (express?). It would probably look something like the former, but `testColl` in the callback arguments looks wrong.